# ORA-00904: \"ASD\": invalid identifier for insert command

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle

I am working for a asp.net website with oracle 11g database in backend. For a button click, i want to execute an update command. I have executed other commands elsewhere (insert,select,delete) but this command however is giving invalid identifier. The code is below:

```
protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.CommandName == "Answer")
        {
            int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);

            // Retrieve the row that contains the button 
            // from the Rows collection.
            GridViewRow row = GridView1.Rows[index];
            TextBox TextBox1 = row.FindControl("TextBox1") as TextBox;
            string ID = row.Cells[0].Text;
            string Date = row.Cells[2].Text;
            string answer = TextBox1.Text;
            string query = "update \"Review2\" set \"Answer\"='" + answer + "' where \"Cust_id\"=" + ID + " and \"Date\"=to_date('" + Date + "','yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss')";
            SqlDataSource1.UpdateCommand = query;
            SqlDataSource1.UpdateCommandType = SqlDataSourceCommandType.Text;
            int result = SqlDataSource1.Update();
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }
    }
```

when i execute this code, no update is being done and at line :int result = SqlDataSource1.Update(); , i get the error,{"ORA-00904: \"ASD\": invalid identifier\n"}. Any solution?

Comment: `string query = "update Review2  set Answer ='" + answer + "' where Cust_id =" + ID + " and Date =to_date('" + Date + "','yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss')";` try this

Comment: [Exploits Of A Mom](http://xkcd.com/327/)

Comment: Did you try to debug and inspect `query`? I strongly recommend to use parameters instead of concatenating a query that is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your update query is wrong in syntax

try the below one

```
string query = @"update Review2 set Answer ='" + answer + "' where Cust_id =" + ID + " and Date =to_date('" + Date + "','yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss')";
```

Note:- Strongly recommend to use parameterized queries inorder to avoid [SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)